# Executing a sql query inside a dataflow using python on PCollection

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to implement one sql query as a transform in dataflow. I loaded a table from bigquery as PCollection. I want to aggregate my data like below query.

`SELECT
  name,
  user_id,
  place,
  SUM(amount) as some_amount ,
  SUM(cost) as sum_cost 
FROM
  [project:test.day_0_test]
GROUP BY 1,2,3`

How I can implement it easily. I heard that Data flow with Java support running sql kind query on P Collection, but correctly python is not supporting. Can any one help me to solve this

Note:

I want to implement this query on a P Collection .. Not to read from bigquery directly

Comment: You need to use a `GroupByKey`. See here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#groupbykey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I edited my answer as you commented on not wanting to run a SQL query directly in BigQuery)

I simulated a file `input.csv` that contains:

```
#input.csv
name1,1,place1,2.,1.5
name1,1,place1,3.,0.5
name1,1,place2,1.,1
name1,2,place3,2.,1.5
name2,2,place3,3.,0.5
```

This is the data that seems you are retrieving from BQ. Your SQL query could be implemented in Beam like:

```
def sum_l(l):                       
    s0, s1 = 0, 0                                         
    for i in range(len(l)):                                        
        s0 += l[i][0]                                                      
        s1 += l[i][1]                
    return [s0, s1] 

with beam.Pipeline(options=po) as p:
     (p | 'Read Input' >> beam.io.ReadFromText("input.csv")
        | 'Split Commas' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.strip().split(','))
        | 'Prepare Keys' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x[:-2], map(float, x[-2:])))
        | 'Group Each Key' >> beam.GroupByKey()
        | 'Make Summation' >> beam.Map(lambda x: [x[0], sum_l([e for e in x[1]])])
        | 'Write Results' >> beam.io.WriteToText('results.csv'))
```

Results are:

```
#results.csv-00000-of-00001
[[u'name1', u'1', u'place2'], [1.0, 1.0]]
[[u'name1', u'2', u'place3'], [2.0, 1.5]]
[[u'name1', u'1', u'place1'], [5.0, 2.0]]
[[u'name2', u'2', u'place3'], [3.0, 0.5]]
```

It's basically the straightforward MapReduce implementation of your query: a key is built for each row, they are grouped together and the final summation happens in the `Map` operation using the function `sum_l`.

I'm not sure why you want to run the query operations in Beam instead of BigQuery though. I recommend trying both approaches as probably it's not possible to be as efficient in Beam as you can be in BigQuery in this case.

Comment: I want to implement this query on a PCOllection. not to read from bigquery directly

Comment: I just edited my answer to implement your SQL query in Python Beam operations, hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: can we save p collection like a variable for future use?

Comment: sure, just assign the result to another variable, such as: `other_po = (p | transforms...)`. You can then use `other_po` for future transformations

Comment: Thanks Willian. Now I want combine two P collection - Like from one P collection I have to fetch ids and take the corresponding rows in second P Collection - How I can do this join operation using python (id from PCollection1, (id, value1,value2,value3) from PCollection 2)

Comment: Looks like you just made a new question on this one. See if my answer helps